# Jacoco Code Coverage Showing Testing Report not Coverage report

Tags: android, jacoco, android-instrumentation

After including Jacoco plugin and enable the testCoverageEnabled = true in app.gradle. I added AndroidJacocoTestRunner java file  After running CreateDebugCoverageReport it gives the Report but not the Code coverage[Test Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DE8nP.png) [image source](https://medium.com/@rafael_toledo/setting-up-an-unified-coverage-report-in-android-with-jacoco-robolectric-and-espresso-ffe239aaf3fa).

Comment: what are the values of main source (src/main/java) and it's classes?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand, Please elaborate.

Comment: What version of Gradle plugin is that? https://proandroiddev.com/unified-code-coverage-for-android-revisited-44789c9b722f

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i found out the solution and its working fine for me.

Comment: If the solution can help, share so it can help others here.

Comment: The coverage Report not generated when the test case result with the exception.

Comment: Did you try skipping for a failed test if only one/few are failing? i.e. don't fail the task if there's an error. I think there's a setting within test task that you can set.